# Hotpoint Washing machine slowly fills with water while not in use, what is wrong?

Tags: washing-machine

Recently I noticed my washer will slowly fill with water when not in use. The machine was in storage for 6 years until we purchased our first home.  Any suggestions would help.

Comment: Water intake valve not closing properly (dirt inside valve?)

Answer (score 1):

Something has one of the solenoid valves stuck open.  You could replace the valves, or perhaps clean them out.